# Docker Image isn't using Java 8?

Tags: docker, java-8, jboss, wildfly

I have a Java EE8 Application which is deployed on JBoss WildFly 16.0.0.Final and it accesses MongoDB using Hibernate OGM.

I have built a customised Docker container using this Docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME

RUN echo $JAVA_HOME
RUN java -version

FROM jboss/wildfly

# ARG are also known as build-time variables
ARG EAR_FILE=./build/libs/GoStopHandle.ear
ARG WILDFLY_MODULES=./wildfly-as/16.0.0.Final/modules

# Add
COPY ${WILDFLY_MODULES}/system/layers/base/org/hibernate/search/ /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/hibernate/search/
COPY ${WILDFLY_MODULES}/org/hibernate/hql/ /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/org/hibernate/hql/
COPY ${WILDFLY_MODULES}/org/hibernate/ogm/ /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/org/hibernate/ogm/
COPY ${WILDFLY_MODULES}/system/layers/base/org/apache/lucene/ /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/lucene/

COPY ./mysqldatabase/mysql/main/ /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/com/mysqldatabase/mysql/main/

ADD standalone.conf /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/

# Add the GoStopHandle ear to the container
ADD ${EAR_FILE} /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh NOTiFY Biggles-1957
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0", "--server-config=standalone-full.xml", "-Dee8.preview.mode=true"]
```

Java 8 appears to be being used:

> Step 6/20 : RUN java -version  ---> Running in 36b53e1a17a2 openjdk
>   version "1.8.0_212" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_212-8u212-b01-1~deb9u1-b01) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b01, mixed mode)

However when I:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8080 gostophandle:latest
```

and in the log I get:

> Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCDateStamps' Error: Could not create the
>   Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program
>   will exit.

Which implies that I'm running on Java 9+. As 'PrintGCDateStamps' works with Java 8.

Outside the Docker contained everything runs fine with:

```
MacBook-Pro:GoStopHandle NOTiFY$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: That Dockerfile builds two images; you get the same final result if you delete everything before the last `FROM` line.

Comment: Not strictly true. If I "delete everything before the last FROM line" I get:      openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Also, I only have 'jdk1.8.0_202.jdk' on my MacBook, not Java 11.

Comment: In your example the only JVM that matters at all is the one in the `jboss/wildfly` base image.  Non-Docker JVMs or JVMs in other images being built in the same Dockerfiles have no effect.

Comment: I'm new to creating my own Docker Containers. I'll upgrade to OpenJDK 11 get it all working locally, then create the image. Many thanks, that's cleared things up a lot.